# Does the Required attribute have any effect on a navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have the following code in an EF data model:

```
[Required]
public IdentityTypeDocument IdentityType { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey(nameof(IdentityType))]
public int? IdentityTypeId { get; set; }
```

Does the first `Required` - on the `IdentityTypeDocument` property mean anything at all versus the second one - the `int` property?

Comment: [Required] has the same meaning as making the FK not nullable. [required] on an int field on the other hand does absolutely nothing - an object of type int is never null.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro An oversight on my part. Please see that I have made the FK property's type to `int?`. I could just have well have changed it to `string`, it doesn't martter. Now, how can the `Required`on the `IdentityTypeDocument` make it non-nullable? It isn't mapped to a DB column.

Comment: it is indirectly mapped to a db column. The IdentityTypeDocument is not nullable, that means it has to be an object with an Id. ChangeTracking should then set the FK to be the same as the PK of the corresponding object. So in this situation both data annotations do exactly the same, as long as none of these (or the type IdentityTypeDocument) is explicitly excluded from the model.

Comment: Your comments make a pretty good answer, @DevilSuichiro.

Comment: A related useful [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396190/is-it-possible-in-ef-core-to-make-a-one-way-navigation-property-required) that talks about making a foreign key as `NOT NULL` using the first approach talked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additionally to the comment conversation and to give this question an answer:

[Required] means the object has to be not null, so on a not nullable type this annotation makes no difference.
For nullable types, it makes no difference if the navigation property or the FK property are annotated this way - if the FK is not null, the navigation property has to be an object with this id or you'll receive an error when trying to save to the database; if the navigation property is not null, ChangeTracking will set the FK to be identical to its PK value.

This means both data annotations mean exactly the same, as they pretty much imply each other - this is assuming the one property is configured correctly to be the FK/navigation property corresponding to the other, and neither of the two properties (or the related type, since then no object of this type will be saved to the database anyways) is excluded from the model explicitly.

Comment: note: With Entity Framework, If you do not use data annotation ([Required] or other annotation) or fluent API to add the validation, it will not throw a DbEntityValidationException, but it will throw DbUpdateException,when you call the context SaveChanges method and it makes a difference if you want to display or log all the validation error messages when exception is fired

Comment: @Xavave: while this is true, the reason for that is different. If you don't configure your model to require a certain value and then pass the null value, while the DBMS expects it, the exception occurs outside of EF on the SQL layer (in fact, if I'm not mistaken it should be an SQLException wrapped in a DbUpdateException). But, since with this setup your model does not match the database schema, there are DbUpdateException's to be expected - the null value was valid by EF, so of course there would be no validation exception.