# Is it possible in EF Core to make a one-way navigation property required?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1, navigation-properties

I am working on a basic group chat system, for which I created these classes:

```
public class Role
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; };
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; };
    public Role Author { get; set; }
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Conversation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; };
    public IList<ConversationParticipant> ConversationParticipants { get; set; };
    public IList<Message> Messages { get; set; };
}

public class ConversationParticipant
{
    public Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

We are using EF Core 3.1 Code-First with migrations.

**I am looking for a way to make `Message.Author` a *required* property**, which should lead to a column in table `Message` that is created as `AuthorId NOT NULL`.

I tried:

```
public static void Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<Message> builder)
{
    builder.HasOne(m => m.Author);
}
```

As this is applied using Add-Migration and Update-Database, the database column `AuthorId` is created, but with `NULL`s allowed.

There does not seem to be a method `IsRequired()` that I can add after `HasOne()`.

I also tried:

```
public static void Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<Message> builder)
{
    builder.Property(m => m.Author).IsRequired();
}
```

but that fails saying

> **The property 'Message.Author' is of type 'Role' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

Doing `.HasOne(...)` followed by `.Property(...).IsRequired()` also does not work:

> **'Author' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Message' because it is configured as a navigation.**

I managed to make `Message.Conversation` required through this:

```
public static void Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<Conversation> builder)
{
    builder.HasMany(c => c.Messages)       // A conversation can have many messages
           .WithOne(e => e.Conversation)   // Each message belongs to at most 1 conversation
           .IsRequired();                  // A message always has a conversation
}
```

However I'd rather not make `Role` aware of Messages, as I will never want to retrieve Messages directly from a Role (this will happen through Conversations and Participants).

My ultimate question is: Is there a way to make `Message.Author` required (NOT NULL), without linking `Message` and `Role` together in a full 1-to-many relationship with a Messages property in `Role`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding `Role`'s foreign key to `Message` and then requiring that property to not be null? Something like:

```
// MessageConfiguration.cs
builder.Property(b => b.RoleId).IsRequired()
```

Comment: Yes this does the trick, using AuthorId (which I also had to add to the Message class) 

Comment: Also works using a magic string to refer to the internally used property: `builder.Property("AuthorId").IsRequired();` (instead of making the property explicit and then using it)

Comment: @PeterB If you add such property (which doesn't exist in the original model) of type `Guid`, it will already be required and no further configuration will be needed. So this definitely is NOT the answer. What you call magic string (and in fact is the so called [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)) though is one of the possible solutions of the original problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev It took me a while to understand what you mean, but I think you mean this: *if* I create a `Guid AuthorId` property myself, then I don't need the `IsRequired()` call because a Guid is never null (while the answer makes it look like I should do both; anyway it got me where I needed to be). Only if I let EF generate the `AuthorId` property then I need the `Property("AuthorId").IsRequired()` call. It all starts making sense now :-) I'm now using the Property(...).IsRequired() approach. I wonder if adding a `[NotNull]` attribute to my Author property might have done the trick.

Comment: @PeterB  Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, but you've got it all right :) And yes, decorating the navigation property with `[Required]` attribute is another way to solve it w/o adding explicit FK property to the model. The point was that when you have explicit FK property, you don't need additional configuration because the type of the property (nullable/not nullable) controls the type of the relationship (optional / required). However adding explicit FK property has pros and cons, that's why saying that one *have* to add one in order to get required relationship is simply wrong.

Comment: @Ivan great points - thanks. Sometimes I forget the conventions EF Core has and thus like to explicitly state those configurations. My answer was not clear on this and I apologize.

Comment: I learned a lot from our exchanges and decided to compose an answer of my own. It is supposed to combine all that we discussed and everything that I learned. Feel free to review :-)

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by @Ben Sampica was helpful and got me where I needed to be, the comments by @Ivan Stoev provided details and clarity that made me think that a more comprehensive answer would be useful.

There are multiple ways to make a foreign key column required (NOT NULL) in the generated table.

1. The simplest is to put `[Required]` on the navigation property:

   ```
   public class Message
   {
       // ...
       [Required] public Role Author { get; set; }
       // ...
   }
   ```

   This will cause EF to create a shadow property `AuthorId` of type `Guid` because Message.Author is a Role and Role.Id is of type Guid. This leads to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL` in case of SQL Server.
   If you omit `[Required]` then EF will use `Guid?`, which leads to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL`, unless you apply one of the other options.
2. You can use an explicit Id property with a type that can't be null:

   ```
   public class Message
   {
       // ...
       public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
       public Role Author { get; set; }
       // ...
   }
   ```

   *Note (i)* - This only works if you follow EF Core [shadow property naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#foreign-key-shadow-properties), which in this case means you must name the Id property `nameof(Author) + nameof(Role.Id)` == `AuthorId`.
   *Note (ii)* - This will break if one day you decide to rename `Author` or `Role.Id` but forget to rename `AuthorId` accordingly.
3. If you can't or don't want to change the Model class, then you can tell EF Core that it needs to treat the shadow property as required:

   ```
   builder.Property("AuthorId").IsRequired();
   ```

   The same *Notes* apply as listed at **2**, with the addition that you could now use `nameof()` to reduce the effort and the risks.

---

In the end I decided to use the `[Required]` approach, because

- It is simple and descriptive,
- No effort needed to think of which shadow property name to use,
- No risk of breaking the shadow property name later on.

This may apply sometimes, not always:

- Input forms may use the Model class attribute to check if a property is required. However it may be a better approach to build your forms around *DTO classes*, and then an attribute on an *EF Model class* may provide no worth for your forms.

Comment: The `[Required]` approach for `Author` property in `Message` class didn't work. I copy - pasted your code in the first post of this thread. I added an `Id` property to the `ConversationParticipant` class and added `DbSet<T>` properties for each of the classes in the `DbContext`. Finally, I ran the `dotnet ef` commands. The result was that the `AuthorId` field in the Messages table was **not** qualified as `NOT NULL`. Which meant it would allow `NULL`.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: Adding the `[Required]` attribute to the `Conversation` property in the `ConversationParticipant` class _did_ work - the resulting table had a foreign key `ConversationId` that was qualified as `NOT NULL`. Adding the `[Required]` attribute for the `Conversation` property in the `Message` class also worked - the Messages table had a field `ConversationId` which was qualified as `NOT NULL`. What gives? What's special about the Conversation class that EF Core is automatically qualifying the corresponding foreign key in relevant tables with `NOT NULL`?